# EntityContext.SaveChange() takes longer time at first call

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using a BindingSource with Entity Framework and when I call the

```
EntityContext.SaveChange();
```

it takes more time to execute then the next times I add New Objects to the binding source and then call the SaveChanges(); method

**EDIT 2**

Details:

At load form event

```
BindingSource.DataSource = EntityContext.Table;
```

The Add New Button

```
BindingSource.AddNew();
Table m_object= (Table)BindingSource.Current;
m_object.ID = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Other object data is being edited using controls bound to its properties

And then the save button

```
BindingSource.EndEdit();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
EntityContext.SaveChanges();
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
```

If I repeated adding and saving several times,I get the following output:

00:00:01.0788243

00:00:00.0316786

00:00:00.0292763

00:00:00.0298630

00:00:00.1127312

It's notable that the first add and save operation takes almost one second more then the next times I add and save.

Answer (score 1):

This can be for a whole lot of reasons, one possible reason is that your database is AutoGrowing when you perform your first commit. Have you got an example of the code which you are executing and the difference in times which you are observing

**EDIT:**

Based on your above code you are creating a new item if one doesn't exist in the database, could it be that the second time you click save you are simply performing an update operation which is quicker inside SQL? (or potentially 0 time if EF detects there are no changes)

Comment: I added detail to the question, and about the differences in time do you mean how much time is between the call of the SaveChanges() calls, also what do you mean by **AutoGrowing**

Comment: @major It would be good if you could quantify what you mean by 'it takes more time to execute then the next times the method called', how much time did it take to call saveChanges the first time, and how much for time did it take the second time? SQL autogrow is a function which expands your database on the fly so that you can fit more stuff in it. This is commonly triggered by an insert statement. Take a look here to learn about autogrow http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/sql-server-database-growth-and-autogrowth-settings/

Comment: @major also take a look at my edit, it may well be that the second time you click save there actually arent any changes to save, or its a quicker update call.

Comment: what I meant by the "next time method called" is that when i call the AddNew() method and edit the object and Call the SaveChanges() again, so it's not like what you assumed that i call the SaveChanges() for the next Time without adding new object to the BindingSource, I had to make the question more accurate before, and about the AutoGrowing I've checked the AutoGrowing Setting and it's still on the default setting with File growth value set to 1 Megabytes.

Comment: Also I've Checked the Database file size from the SQL Management Studio> MYDataBase > Properties and it remains the same after adding the saving the first object it still the same, I don't know if there is a better way to make sure that the AutoGrowing Is not Occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Could the reason(s) that Luke provided, but also don't forget about JIT (just-in-time) compiling. When you run your C# application, it's all compiled to MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language) and when you start calling methods for the first time, JIT has to compile them to native code and run optimizations to fit the OS it is running on. This is a common reason why the first time you do an extensive operation there could be seconds of delay as opposed to the expected milliseconds.

Mono has the AOT (ahead-of-time) compiling capibility, which means that it skips the step and avoids that extra time the first time you call a method, but you sacrifice in performance elsewhere.

There is also a tool that allows you to pre-compile C# natively on windows, but i don't remember what it is called.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget about the EF Change Tracker that could be caching data after the first operation. Based on the MergeOption and the operation you are performing, EF might choose to not even call to the database. I would run the test with SQL Profiler on to see the difference in actual calls to the database.  Also, check if the subsequent calls use the same db connection.